# I need a minimal example specifically for the Facebook Graph API (using PHP)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook SDK changed since last time I used it. 
I want to crate a website that pulls out information from a closed group the user is already joined to. Last time I used javascript and now I have to use PHP that is a little bit new for me.

The examples on facebook don't give a good simple example of what is in the SDK (..in my opinion). 
My main problem is connecting the facebook to my website and getting the website to sync with the app.

In "App Domains" I inserted the "localhost", In "Site URL" I used the exact directory of PHP files (`http://localhost/test/facebook-g.api/`) and seted up the right item in "Items for review" (user_groups).

This is what I have till now in my code:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'autoload.php';

    use src\Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use src\Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use src\Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use src\Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use src\Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use src\Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use src\Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use src\Facebook\GraphObject;
    use src\Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
    use src\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use src\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;


    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '000','a866372f873730e7000000000009' );
```

I need a minimal example for how to start using the Graph API and more specifically how to connect me page to it. I know I need to generate somehow the token code which I'm not sure how to do that too. The example on facebook don't include which files from the SDK I have to add to me code.

I Hope this post will be useful for others like me next time they google :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this tutorial. It has everything in it including the access token thing.

http://www.benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4/

I hope this will be useful for other users googleing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about referring to the actual Facebook docs? Have a look at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

or the PHP SDK Github repo at

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/

to get started.

Example code:

```
<?php

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('YOUR_APP_ID','YOUR_APP_SECRET');

// Use one of the helper classes to get a FacebookSession object.
//   FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
//   FacebookCanvasLoginHelper
//   FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper
// or create a FacebookSession with a valid access token:
$session = new FacebookSession('access-token-here');

// Get the GraphUser object for the current user:

try {
  $me = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'GET', '/me'
  ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
  echo $me->getName();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
  // The Graph API returned an error
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  // Some other error occurred
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, the docs aren't so accurate. they don't include which files I have to include in my .php file, I'm using the "PHP SDK Github repo " and same there, There isn't anything that explains  right what's going on there. I'm not a PHP expert so It's hard for me to understand by myself.

Comment: The Github repo contain a complete example file. I don't exactly understand what is complicated about copying this (and the PHP SDK) to a new file, adding the app_id, saving it to your webserver and calling it via a browser...

Comment: And, by the way, if you want to access groups, you need the `user_group` permission which is quite difficult to get granted from FB: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_groups